# Create Cumulative Recurring SUM in MySQL for Last "x" Days

Tags: mysql, sum

My business sales run through a very unique annual cycle based on seasons throughout the year. I can't get a sense of my growth from week to week, or month to month. What I really need is a running total showing the last 365 days -- every day. When I span that across an entire year, I can really see how my business is growing.

Below, I have just made up data to explain my desire.  I have an SQL query already that gives me Year, Week and Sales. Here is my query (it involves some joining, but it works):

```
SELECT
YEAR(arrPurch.PurchaseDate) as YEAR,
Week(arrPurch.PurchaseDate) AS Week,
SUM(ROUND(arrPurch.Credits*1.85+arrPurch.Price,0)) AS `Sales`
FROM
arrangementPurchases AS arrPurch
INNER JOIN catalog_dev_arrangements AS catDEVarr ON arrPurch.ArrangementID = catDEVarr.ArrangementID
INNER JOIN members ON arrPurch.MemberID = members.MemberID
WHERE arrPurch.PurchaseDate >= '2015-01-04'
GROUP BY Year, Week
ORDER BY Year, Week
```

Now, what I need is code that will allow me to get the fourth column, "Cumulative Year", taking into account the current week, plus sales from all 51 weeks proceeding it.  Then, every week, I'll have a solid sense of the state of my sales growth, knowing that every week cumulative takes into account all of the seasons in my annual sales cycle.

```
Year      Week         Sales           Cumulative Year
-------------------------------------------------------
2017       01          24,292          2,467,488
2017       02          32,838          2,471,433
2017       03          33,283          2,470,212
```

Please help :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a sub-query that gets the sum of sales from a give year week to 51 weeks ago. See sample demo below

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ce6dd0/1

```
select
YEAR(arrPurch.PurchaseDate) as YEAR,
Week(arrPurch.PurchaseDate) AS Week,
SUM(ROUND(arrPurch.Credits*1.85+arrPurch.Price,0)) AS `Sales`,
(select sum(ROUND(t.Credits*1.85+t.Price,0))
      FROM arrangementPurchases AS t
      INNER JOIN catalog_dev_arrangements AS catDEVarr ON t.ArrangementID = catDEVarr.ArrangementID
      INNER JOIN members ON t.MemberID = members.MemberID
  where YEARWEEK(t.purchaseDate)
  between YEARWEEK(arrPurch.purchaseDate - INTERVAL 51 WEEK) 
 and YEARWEEK(arrPurch.purchaseDate)) as `Cumulative_Year`
FROM arrangementPurchases AS arrPurch
INNER JOIN catalog_dev_arrangements AS catDEVarr ON arrPurch.ArrangementID = catDEVarr.ArrangementID
INNER JOIN members ON arrPurch.MemberID = members.MemberID
WHERE arrPurch.PurchaseDate >= '2015-01-04'
GROUP BY Year, Week
ORDER BY Year, Week
```

Comment: We are getting close! When I post your code, I get the following error: `com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'arrPurch.ArrangementID' in 'on clause'`.  I did notice that you inputted the following: `FROM arrangementPurchases AS t`. I think that left my arrPurch reference dangling.  So, then I replaced all your instances of "t" with "arrPurch", and ended up with working results, but the SUM of every line was the same.  It seemed to be the total sum of all my sales, since 2015. Is it possible `arrangementPurchases AS t` was mistaken?

Comment: I fix it so please try again. Pls copy and paste then run again. Thanks.

Comment: I just went to your example demo. I modified it slightly, and found that it does in fact work.  See my version here: [http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f16198/2]. Now I just need to figure out how to make it work with my original data, and solve the error I'm getting.

Comment: The code is calculating right now, but it may take a while, because there is a lot of data to process.  There are no errors, so far, so that's great.  I'll let you know if it works!

Comment: As a variation to this, could you tell me how to get a RUNNING TOTAL instead of an ANNUALIZED SUM out of the same query.